# No funciona mi formulario en MySQL-PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estoy creando una página de administración de productos de una tienda ficticia, como dice en el título tengo un problema con los scripts, lo que pasa que cuando le doy a insertar no pasa absolutamente nada, eso que me estuve guiando con una página parecida, me parece raro que no me esté funcionando, ¿que estaré haciendo mal?. Agradezco su ayuda.
Acá está la página entera http://www.mediafire.com/folder/r4r7mocb882g8/v2

```js
// funciones del minisistema para registar los productos
function checkForm() {
  // preparar mensaje y control de error
  var mensaje = "ATENCION!!!... Ingrese:\n";
  var error = false;
  // capturar datos del formulario
  var marca = document.getElementById("dataMRCA").value;
  var descripcion = document.getElementById("dataDESC").value;
  var origen = document.getElementById("dataORIG").value;
  var precio = document.getElementById("dataPCIO").value;
  var categoria = document.getElementById("dataCATE").value;
  // validar datos
  if (marca == "") {
    error = true;
    mensaje = mensaje + "Marca:\n";
  } // endif
  if (descripcion == "") {
    error = true;
    mensaje = mensaje + "Descripción:\n";
  } // endif 
  if (origen == "") {
    error = true;
    mensaje = mensaje + "Teléfono no puede ser vacío:\n";
  } // endif
  if (precio == "U$S") {
    error = true;
    mensaje = mensaje + "El precio no puede ser signo de dólar:\n";
  } // endif
  if (isntaNum(precio)) { // is Not a Number
    error = true;
    mensaje = mensaje + "El precio tiene que ser numérico:\n";
  } // endif           
  if (categoria == "") {
    error = true;
    mensaje = mensaje + "Categoría:\n";
  } // endif

  // controlar error
  if (error) {
    // mostrar mensaje
    window.alert(mensaje);
  } else {
    // enviar formulario
    document.getElementById("dataFORM").submit();
  } // endif                         
} // end function

function checkID() {
  // preparar mensaje y control de error
  var mensaje = "ATENCION!!!... Ingrese:\n";
  var error = false;
  // capturar datos del formulario
  var id = document.getElementById("dataID").value;
  // validar datos
  if (id == "") {
    error = true;
    mensaje = mensaje + "El ID no puede ser vacío:\n";
  } // endif
  if (isntaNum(id)) {
    error = true;
    mensaje = mensaje + "El ID solo puede ser numérico:\n";
  } // endif 

  // controlar error
  if (error) {
    // mostrar mensaje
    window.alert(mensaje);
  } else {
    // enviar formulario
    document.getElementById("dataFORM").submit();
  } // endif                         
} // end function

function checkDEL() {
  var confirma = window.confirm("¿Seguro que lo quieres eliminar?");
  if (confirma) {
    // enviar formulario
    document.getElementById("dataFORM").submit();
  } // endif
} // end function

function setPage(url) {
  window.location = url;
} // end function
```

```html
<?php
    // PROCESO PRODUCTOS INS
    
    // conectar al servidor de Base de Datos
    include "conection.inc";
    // capturar datos del formulario
    $marca           = utf8_decode($_POST["MRCA"]);
    $descripcion     = utf8_decode($_POST["DESC"]);
    $origen          = utf8_decode($_POST["ORIG"]);
    $precio          = $_POST["PCIO"];
    $categoria       = utf8_decode($_POST["CATE"]);
    // crear sentencia SQL para INSERTAR registro
    $sql  = "INSERT INTO productos";
    $sql .= "(idPROD,mrcaPROD,descPROD,origPROD,pcioPROD,catePROD)";
    $sql .= "VALUES";
    $sql .= "(null,'$marca','$descripcion','$origen','$precio','$categoria')";
    // ejecutar sentencia SQL
    mysql_query($sql,$conex);
    // cerrar conexión
    mysql_close($conex);
    // volver automáticamente al formulario (redirigir)
    header("location: insPROD.php");
?>

  // index abajo

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pageStyle.css" />
    <title>MarketCam Pagina</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="funcPROD.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--header --->
    <?php
    include "header.inc";
?>

      <!--menú prpal --->
      <?php
    include "menuPpal.inc";
?>



        <p id="descripcion">
          ......
        </p>
        <div id="contenido">
          <fieldset id="formCLGO">
            <legend id="pagTit">insertando</legend>
            <form id="dataFORM" method="POST" action="insPROD.php">
              <table id="tableList">
                <tr>
                  <td id="marca">Marca: </td>
                  <td><input id="dataMRCA" type="text" maxlength="30" title="Máximo 30 caracteres" name="MRCA" />
                  </td>
                </tr> <br />

                <tr>
                  <td id="descripcion">Descripción: </td>
                  <td><input id="dataDESC" type="text" maxlength="300" title="Máximo 300 caracteres" name="DESC" />
                  </td>
                </tr> <br />

                <tr>
                  <td id="origen">Origen: </td>
                  <td>
                    <select id="dataORIG" name="ORIG" title="Selecionar origen">
                      <option value="">Seleccione el país de origen</option>
                      <option value="USA">USA</option>
                      <option value="Alemania">Alemania</option>
                      <option value="China">China</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                </tr> <br />

                <tr>
                  <td id="precio">Precio: </td>
                  <td><input id="dataPCIO" type="text" maxlength="10" title="Máximo 5 caracteres" placeholder="U$S" />
                  </td>
                </tr> <br />

                <tr>
                  <td id="categoria">Categoría: </td>
                  <td>
                    <select id="dataCATE">
                      <option>Seleccione su categoría</option>
                      <option value="Cámaras">Cámaras</option>
                      <option value="Trípodes">Trípodes</option>
                      <option value="Lentes">Lentes</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                </tr> <br />

                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="button" value="Insertar" onclick="checkForm();" />
                    <input type="reset" value="Cancelar" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </form>
          </fieldset>
        </div>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Puede que tu código tenga varios fallos. Pero empieza a depurar. ¿Seguro que el formulario se está enviando? Pon un alert en la parte de envío para verificarlo. Luego, si se está enviando, debes controlar los datos del POST, lo cual no haces. Tampoco se ve el formulario (HTML). Debes verificar la versión de PHP, si es v. 7+  tus consultas a la base de datos no funcionarán, porque la API `mysql_*` que estás usando no funciona en PHP 7.

Comment: El problema que cuando le doy a "insertar" no hace absoltamente.

Comment: El formulario está en el link que puse

Comment: Aclaro que soy nuevo en esto, necesito que alguien pueda decirme lo que está mal, ya verifiqué un montón de veces y no veo el error. Al inicio del todo está el link de la página.

Comment: bueno la primer recomendación que hago, es escribe la query en el mismo renglón, pues no veo el por que partirla en múltiples y luego concatenarla

Comment: No sé, me estuve guiando con una página hecha con la misma idea y esa funcionó, pudiste ver el error que me mandé?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error de `javascript`. Estás usando la función:

```
isntaNum().
```

Probablemente quisiste usar:

`isNaN().`

Para ver los errores de `javascript` puedes utilizar la consola del navegador.

Comment: aún así recuerda que esa función para un 33 le daría false pues `isNaN` se encarga de validar que un valor no es un númer

Comment: me fijé y no es ese el problema

Comment: Podrías describir qué otro error tienes?. Logré reproducir tu código y a mi me funciona perfecto.

Comment: Sigue sin hacer nada el formulario?.